# App status: Rejected | Problema con el lanzamiento de mi app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

Vengo porque me estoy volviendo loco tratando de poder lanzar mi app y no logro evitar que me rechacen mi app.

El problema que me marca Google es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en mi ficha de Play Store estos son los datos de mi app publicos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que los errores están aquí. Pero ya probé cambiar todas las palabras sospechosas que podrían considerarse cómo tales. Pero ni así.

Si alguien en base a su experiencia me puede dar algún consejo se lo agradezco 
Un saludo!

Comment: Ese tipo de problemas los reporta cuando usas nombres de marcas registradas, para lo cual previamente tienes que pedir permiso al propietario de la marca (y no sé por qué vía hacerle saber a Google que tienes el permiso). Quizás "mundial Qatar" sean términos registrados por la FIFA? O tal vez simplemente google los considera "peligrosos" en el sentido de que podrían proliferar apps con esos títulos que solo sean spam.

Comment: Que palabras podría poner ? Quizás "Mundial 2022"?

Comment: Ni idea. Yo no veo normal que poner "Mundial Qatar" esté prohibido, a lo mejor la razón es otra, pero yo probaría con eso de "Mundial 2022" que parece menos problemático.

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente, Google Play tiene una "politica de interpretación" la cual no se está cumpliendo, de acuerdo a tu mensaje:

> Issue with your app Your app's store listing appears to contain
> words, phrases, images or videos you may not have permission to use.

que indica:

> Problema con tu aplicación La ficha de Play Store de tu aplicación
> parece contener palabras, frases, imágenes o videos que quizás no
> tenga permiso para usar.

Por ejemplo, veo la imagen con el texto: "2022 World Cup QATAR", debes tener cuidado ya que esto puede hacer alusiòn a una marca registrada que es:

> Copa Mundial de la FIFA Catar 2022™ (FIFA World Cup Qatar 2022™)

Ademàs de las imagenes, debes evitar agregar textos alusivos a marcas registradas en la ficha de tu aplicaciòn, para evitar problemas con tu aplicaciòn, puedes poner por ejemplo:

[image: Android jorgesys ioana bosca qatar2022]